# DexNav Shiny Chaining Questions

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I'm familiar with the general rules for shiny chaining using the DexNav in Pokemon Omega Ruby and Alpha Sapphire.

Compiled from various sites:

- Leaving the area will break your chain.
- Whenever a player captures or feints a **hidden** Pokemon of any species, the chain increases.
- Encountering anything but a hidden wild Pokemon (whether trainer or regular wild Pokemon) will break your chain.
- Failing to capture or defeat the wild Pokemon **for any reason** will break the chain.
- Once it appears, failing to encounter a hidden wild Pokemon in the wild **for any reason** (walking too fast, walking too far away, or taking too long and letting it run away) will break the chain. Bringing up the menu once the Pokemon has appeared will not stop the timer on the Pokemon running. From my own experience, NPCs walking around in the grass will also scare away hidden Pokemon. Stay away from those buggers.
- The DexNav does not *have* to be used to keep a chain going, and receiving a "The Pokemon couldn't be found..." message while using the search feature does **not** break the chain.
- Every 5 successive encounters increases the level of hidden Pokemon by 1. Every hundred encounters, this level bonus resets to 0.

Even though the items I'm curious about aren't explicitly stated above, I don't want to assume that they're true or false implicitly.

My concerns:

- If a **shiny** Pokemon is encountered, and **fainted**, does it break the chain? (for instance, I encounter a shiny that I already have, and I want to keep chaining for a different one)
- Confirm that it does *not* have to be the same Pokemon encountered every time in order maintain the chain, as long as it's a hidden Pokemon encountered.
- Capturing a shiny Pokemon also breaks the chain, right? Otherwise you could just keep chaining in the area until you have all available Pokemon. Which I'm totally fine with if that's the case lol, but I'm assuming not.
- When the bonus that affects the hidden, wild Pokemon's level and potential is reset, does this break the chain? (I'm assuming not)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer every question following your order:

- Fainting or catching a shiny Pokemon doesn't break the chain, but it will reset the chance to find another shiny Pokemon to the default value.
- No, you can encounter different hidden Pokemon while chaining without breaking it. As [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DexNav#Chaining) states:

  > A chain builds every time the player captures or defeats a hidden Pokémon of **any species**.
- As said above, catching a shiny Pokemon will reset the chance, but it doesn't break the chain.
- No, reaching a chain of 100 doesn't break the chain, it will only reset the Pokemon level bonus. According to a previous version of the [DexNav](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DexNav) page:

  > The chance of encountering a Shiny Pokémon increases, estimated to reach 0.5% per encounter after 40 chained encounters, and remain at that rate as long as the chain continues. *There is thus a 50% chance of encountering a Shiny Pokémon in the first (roughly) 130 chained encounters*.

  (This means that you need a chain of 100+ to get a decent chance of a shiny encounter.)

Comment: This answer seems out of date now.

Answer (score -1):

Chains don’t matter. Chains do not increase the chance of finding shiny Pokémon. When you use the DexNav, it’s a 1/512 chance - the same as Masada odds with a shiny charm. However, if you use DexNav and have a shiny charm, it’s a 1/200 chance of finding shinies.